# Is it appropriate to offer a bounty in order to gain attention for an answer?

Tags: discussion

Ok, so this question about absolutism was a good one.

I really wanted to give a good answer, and I think I did here: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/6383/1039

Unfortunately, while the question gained a lot of interest, none of the answers really did- and by the time I posted, it was so low that I think it got ignored.

I'm toying with awarding a bounty. Would that be wrong? And, what if, in the end, I really think mine is the best answr? Could I award it back to myself? That just seems wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot award a bounty to your own answer. Frankly there isn't a great way to get attention to your own answers if they don't get it for some other reason.

If you think you've already nailed the best possible answer, I'd just not worry about it. Promote it off-site and draw in outside votes!

If you think there is any angle not covered or somebody could work up a more comprehensive or clear answer, then offering a bounty will draw attention to the question and incite more good answers. Even with a good answer already, sometimes a question deserves more good answer coverage. In this case your answer will also gain attention, but others might jump in and build on it. Usually this is a win/win.